# Sender of Sub Menu

Tags: vb.net

Alright so I am going to try and explain this the best I can.

I am trying to get the sender.name from a sub menu in my menustrip

```
Menu1
-----Menu3
----------Menu3
```

I want to set a label text to "Menu1 Menu2 Menu3"

I don't know if this is enough information or explained enough I am trying my best.

Comment: You haven't really explained all that well.  Are you saying that, when the user clicks a menu item, you want to get the entire ancestry chain of that menu item, e.g. in the Click event handler of Menu3 you want to be able to discover that it is a child of Menu2 and that that is a child of Menu1?

Comment: That's what I would like i just don't know how to explain that...

Comment: We're all Windows users so lack of programming experience is no excuse for not being able to explain what steps you want to perform in an application.  Nowhere did you mention clicking the menu item but everyone who uses Windows knows about clicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g.

```
Private Sub Menu3ToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Menu3ToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim menuItemTexts As New List(Of String)
    Dim menuItem = DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)

    menuItemTexts.Add(menuItem.Text)

    While menuItem.OwnerItem IsNot Nothing
        menuItem = DirectCast(menuItem.OwnerItem, ToolStripMenuItem)
        menuItemTexts.Insert(0, menuItem.Text)
    End While

    MessageBox.Show(String.Join(" ", menuItemTexts))
End Sub
```